# The electrostatics problem

Tags: electrostatics

This question is on electrostatics. Think a conductor which has 19 excess electrons. Now I make it to have contact with a neutral object. Then electron transfer should happen. But we have two theories,  one of conservation of charge and one is that charge is divided equally between two objects. Then in this process of electron transferring each of these both objects will have 9.5 electrons which violates the conservation of charge. So how will the transaction of electrons happen?  Please help!

Comment: How could a conductor have exactly 19 electrons

Comment: A conductor Can have 38 electrons and I can touch it with another nutral conductor then both would have 19 electrons

Comment: that’s not my question. Rather how do you know with a very good precision that a specific conductor can have exactly 19 or 38 electrons?

Comment: The question starts to get meaningless when you talk about precision on the atomic or sub atomic level

Comment: I am asking the question with point of view of a higher secondary student who has dealt with electrostatics only

Comment: I totally agree with you. Such questions can come to mind. Simple questions like why $$F=ma$$. Such questions can not be answered because it’s a fundamental equation of the universe. Similarly there’s no answer to your question as we cannot determine the exact amount of atomic particles in a certain quantity of substance, we can only estimate the number of atomic particles.

Comment: Can't we determine the charge of a charged body?

Comment: @physics2000 I am sorry I should have said that the conductor has 19 excess electrons. Thanks for spotting my mistake.

Comment: here’s a simple question. Suppose there are 5 * 10^12 electrons in empty space. Now we know that the charge of each electron is 1.6 * 10^(-19) therefore the total charge is 5 * 10^(-7) coulombs. So is it possible to count those many number of electrons and then multiply by the charge of an electron and obtain a answer?  If so you should understand that in calculating the charge of something there’s a limit to the precision of calculation.

Comment: @physics2000 this is a question about class 12 electrostatics like. I can bet you know that in high schools we are taught if a charged body has excess electrons then it transfers electrons in a neutral body after making contact keeping them equally charged at equilibrium.

Comment: exactly. But you see the problem with your question is not that it’s wrong that you asked such a question. Even I have meaningless questions. That’s the way we learn. But I already told you, that you cannot say exactly the number of electrons in a charged body. Even if say one electron is excess that means it will create a potential difference which will lead to current flow. But you should consider in the real world nothing is perfect plus there’s air and the electron can be stripped away from the body by air molecules.

Comment: Also as Rodrigo Fontana said electrostatics treats electricity not as a flow of electrons but just as a flow of charge.

Comment: maybe I’m not capable to answer your question. Thanks though :-)

Answer (score 2):

I would say that, in practice of macroscopic physics for which the classical electrodynamics theory was built, there is no such precision as to transfer electrons at a unit rate as you quote. I mean: in Maxwell equations there is no sense in thinking a single electron as good candidate for its dynamic/static. Nor a small group of them.

I would guess the question should be addressed via quantum mechanics: you have to write the wave functions of both conductors and the interaction term with the proper boundary conditions to your problem, so to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think, If both quantities are equivalent for the two objects then 9-9 electrons are transfer in both conductors, and remaining one electron are  stuck in its main conducter up to equivalent of other two conducter.

Reason of stucking of electron is due to equal forces, it's not in opposite direction but in another axis(in electrons there is no simple physical laws are applicable so the Einstien's theory of relativity is not applicable and put forth quantum theory for it and string theory.) so the electron balance between two conducters and stuck.

You can't find of this answer in small amount of quantities because the value of equations in electrostatics are aprox.